# application architecture challenge with multiple views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am very new to iOS development, and would like to build the following app:

- First screen is a tab bar view with 4 tabs
- 3 tabs are very simple, but the 4th takes you out of the tab bar view with multiple views in a sequence. it's basically an exercise throughout 10 screens (I dont care if there is a nav bar in those or not) and at the end you get a score and go back to the main tab bar view.

How would you suggest that I approach this given that I have the following requirements:

- at any given page at the exercise, the user can cancel and go back to the main tab bar view (how can I go back to that specific page from the middle of the exercise? or at the end of the exercise?)
- each page has some buttons and stuff, so its not a series of images - user takes action and it has to be recorded and used at the final screen (for the score)
  -should I use a scroll view with pagination? I read about it, and not sure if it fits my needs.
- should I display the 10 view controller modally and have a separate UIViewController for each?

I know it's more than one question, but I want to give the context and I believe that one answer of the overall strategy could answer all those questions altogether.

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just put a navigation controller inside of your fourth tab, then use it to navigate through question views.

Whenever you want to go back to the start of this exercise, use `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in `Cancel` method.

If you do not want to show the nav bar, you can set

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: But will I need 10 different view controllers in this case? Does it mean that i cant present those modally?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
 tabBarController.delegate=self;
    Screen1 *screen1=[[Screen1 alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]screen1];
 Screen2 *screen2=[[Screen2 alloc]init];
 UINavigationController * nav3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:screen2];
UIWindow *samplewindow = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
NSArray *controllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav2,nav3, nil];
        tabBarController.viewControllers=controllers;
     [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 samplewindow.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [samplewindow addSubview:self.viewController.view];
     [samplewindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Add this code in AppDelegate.m then it will work fine.